# In iText 7 java how do you update Link text after it's already been added to the document

Tags: itext

I am using iText7 to build a table of contents for my document. I know all the section names before I start, but don't know what the page numbers will be. My current process is to create a table on the first page and create all the Link objects with generic text "GO!". Then as I add sections I add  through the link objects and update the text with the page numbers that I figured out as I created the document.

However, at the end, what gets written out for the link is "GO!", not the updated page number values I set as I was creating the rest of the document.

I did set the immediateFlush flag to false when I created the Document.

```
public class UpdateLinkTest {

    PdfDocument pdfDocument = null;
    List<Link>links = null;

    Color hyperlinkColor = new DeviceRgb(0, 102, 204);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String[]>notes = new ArrayList<>();

        notes.add(new String[] {"me", "title", "this is my text" });
        notes.add(new String[] {"me2", "title2", "this is my text 2" });

        new UpdateLinkTest().exportPdf(notes, new File("./test2.pdf"));
    }

    public void exportPdf(List<String[]> notes, File selectedFile) throws Exception {
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(selectedFile);
        pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4, false);

        // add the table of contents table
        addSummaryTable(notes, document);

        // add a page break
        document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));

        // add the body of the document
        addNotesText(notes, document);

        document.close();
    }

    private void addSummaryTable(List<String[]> notes, Document document) {
        links = new ArrayList<>();

        Table table = new Table(3);
        float pageWidth = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
        table.setWidth(pageWidth-document.getLeftMargin()*2);

        // add header
        addCell("Author", table, true);
        addCell("Title", table, true);
        addCell("Page", table, true);

        int count = 0;
        for (String[] note : notes) {

            addCell(note[0], table, false);
            addCell(note[1], table, false);

            Link link = new Link("Go!", PdfAction.createGoTo(""+ (count+1)));
            links.add(link);

            addCell(link, hyperlinkColor, table, false);

            count++;
        }
        document.add(table);
    }

    private void addNotesText(List<String[]> notes, Document document)
            throws Exception {

        int count = 0;
        for (String[] note : notes) {
            int numberOfPages = pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();

            Link link = links.get(count);
            link.setText(""+(numberOfPages+1));

            Paragraph noteText = new Paragraph(note[2]);
            document.add(noteText);

            noteText.setDestination(++count+"");
            
            if (note != notes.get(notes.size()-1))
                document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
        }
    }

    private static void addCell(String text, Table table, boolean b) {
        Cell c1 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(text));
        table.addCell(c1);
    }

    private static void addCell(Link text, Color backgroundColor, Table table, boolean b) {
        Cell c1 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(text));
        text.setUnderline();
        text.setFontColor(backgroundColor);
        table.addCell(c1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you minimize your code sample so that it's easily reproducible by people who don't have `IJavaNote` interface definition and `JavaNoteImpl` class definition? Your `fileOutputStream` is also unused - probably can be dropped from the code sample as well. I can imagine it's possible to reproduce the issue with a simpler code sample without tables etc. Whoever picks your question up will much more likely be able to help you if they can easily run your code. I am sure there is a good way to help with your use case.

Comment: I updated the example. It's now simpler and completely self contained (no external classes). Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

Quite more work needs to be done compared to the code you have now because the changes to the elements don't take any effect once you've added them to the document. Immediate flush set to false allows you to relayout the elements, but that does not happen automatically. The way you calculate the current page the paragraph will be placed on (`int numberOfPages = pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();`) is not bulletproof because in some cases pages might be added in advance, even if the content is not going to be placed on them immediately.

There is a very low level way to achieve your goal but with the recent version of iText (7.1.15) there is a simpler way as well, which still requires some work though. Basically your use case is very similar to `target-counter` concept in CSS, with `page` counter being the target one in your case. To support target counters in `pdfHTML` add-on we added new capabilities to our `layout` module which are possible to use directly as well.

To start off, we are going to tie our `Link` elements to the corresponding `Paragraph` elements that they will point to. We are going to do it with `ID` property in layout:

```
link.setProperty(Property.ID, String.valueOf(count));
```

```
noteText.setProperty(Property.ID, String.valueOf(count));
```

Next up, we are going to create custom renderers for our `Link` elements and `Paragraph` elements. Those custom renderers will interact with `TargetCounterHandler` which is the new capability in `layout` module I mentioned in the introduction. The idea is that during layout operation the paragraph will remember the page on which it was placed and then the corresponding link element (remember, link elements are connected to paragraph elements) will ask `TargetCounterHandler` during layout process of that link element which page the corresponding paragraph was planed on. So in a way, `TargetCounterHandler` is a connector.

Code for custom renderers:

```
private static class CustomParagraphRenderer extends ParagraphRenderer {
    public CustomParagraphRenderer(Paragraph modelElement) {
        super(modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new CustomParagraphRenderer((Paragraph) modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutResult layout(LayoutContext layoutContext) {
        LayoutResult result = super.layout(layoutContext);
        TargetCounterHandler.addPageByID(this);
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
private static class CustomLinkRenderer extends LinkRenderer {
    public CustomLinkRenderer(Link link) {
        super(link);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutResult layout(LayoutContext layoutContext) {
        Integer targetPageNumber = TargetCounterHandler.getPageByID(this, getProperty(Property.ID));
        if (targetPageNumber != null) {
            setText(String.valueOf(targetPageNumber));
        }
        return super.layout(layoutContext);
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new CustomLinkRenderer((Link) getModelElement());
    }
}
```

Don't forget to assign the custom renderers to their elements:

```
link.setNextRenderer(new CustomLinkRenderer(link));
```

```
noteText.setNextRenderer(new CustomParagraphRenderer(noteText));
```

Now, the other thing we need to do it `relayout`. You already set `immediateFlush` to false and this is needed for `relayout` to work. Relayout is needed because on the first layout loop we will not know all the positions of the paragraphs, but we will already have placed the links on the pages by the time we know those positions. So we need the second pass to use the information about page numbers the paragraphs will reside on and set that information to the links.

Relayout is pretty straightforward - once you've put all the content you just need to call a single dedicated method:

```
// For now we have to prepare the handler for relayout manually, this is going to be improved
// in future iText versions
((DocumentRenderer)document.getRenderer()).getTargetCounterHandler().prepareHandlerToRelayout();
document.relayout();
```

One caveat is that for now you also need to subclass the `DocumentRenderer` since there is an additional operation that needs to be done that is not performed under the hood - propagation of the target counter handler to the root renderer we will be using for the second layout operation:

```
// For now we have to create a custom renderer for the root document to propagate the
// target counter handler to the renderer that will be used on the second layout process
// This is going to be improved in future iText versions
private static class CustomDocumentRenderer extends DocumentRenderer {
    public CustomDocumentRenderer(Document document, boolean immediateFlush) {
        super(document, immediateFlush);
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        CustomDocumentRenderer renderer = new CustomDocumentRenderer(document, immediateFlush);
        renderer.targetCounterHandler = new TargetCounterHandler(targetCounterHandler);
        return renderer;
    }
}
```

```
document.setRenderer(new CustomDocumentRenderer(document, false));
```

And now we are done. Here is our visual result:

[image: result]

Complete code looks as follows:

```
public class UpdateLinkTest {

    PdfDocument pdfDocument = null;

    Color hyperlinkColor = new DeviceRgb(0, 102, 204);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String[]> notes = new ArrayList<>();

        notes.add(new String[] {"me", "title", "this is my text" });
        notes.add(new String[] {"me2", "title2", "this is my text 2" });

        new UpdateLinkTest().exportPdf(notes, new File("./test2.pdf"));
    }

    public void exportPdf(List<String[]> notes, File selectedFile) throws Exception {
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(selectedFile);
        pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4, false);

        document.setRenderer(new CustomDocumentRenderer(document, false));

        // add the table of contents table
        addSummaryTable(notes, document);

        // add a page break
        document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));

        // add the body of the document
        addNotesText(notes, document);

        // For now we have to prepare the handler for relayout manually, this is going to be improved
        // in future iText versions
        ((DocumentRenderer)document.getRenderer()).getTargetCounterHandler().prepareHandlerToRelayout();
        document.relayout();

        document.close();
    }

    private void addSummaryTable(List<String[]> notes, Document document) {
        Table table = new Table(3);
        float pageWidth = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
        table.setWidth(pageWidth-document.getLeftMargin()*2);

        // add header
        addCell("Author", table, true);
        addCell("Title", table, true);
        addCell("Page", table, true);

        int count = 0;
        for (String[] note : notes) {
            addCell(note[0], table, false);
            addCell(note[1], table, false);

            Link link = new Link("Go!", PdfAction.createGoTo(""+ (count+1)));
            link.setProperty(Property.ID, String.valueOf(count));
            link.setNextRenderer(new CustomLinkRenderer(link));

            addCell(link, hyperlinkColor, table, false);

            count++;
        }
        document.add(table);
    }

    private void addNotesText(List<String[]> notes, Document document) {

        int count = 0;
        for (String[] note : notes) {
            Paragraph noteText = new Paragraph(note[2]);
            noteText.setProperty(Property.ID, String.valueOf(count));
            noteText.setNextRenderer(new CustomParagraphRenderer(noteText));
            document.add(noteText);

            noteText.setDestination(++count+"");

            if (note != notes.get(notes.size()-1))
                document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
        }
    }

    private static void addCell(String text, Table table, boolean b) {
        Cell c1 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(text));
        table.addCell(c1);
    }

    private static void addCell(Link text, Color backgroundColor, Table table, boolean b) {
        Cell c1 = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(text));
        text.setUnderline();
        text.setFontColor(backgroundColor);
        table.addCell(c1);
    }

    private static class CustomLinkRenderer extends LinkRenderer {
        public CustomLinkRenderer(Link link) {
            super(link);
        }

        @Override
        public LayoutResult layout(LayoutContext layoutContext) {
            Integer targetPageNumber = TargetCounterHandler.getPageByID(this, getProperty(Property.ID));
            if (targetPageNumber != null) {
                setText(String.valueOf(targetPageNumber));
            }
            return super.layout(layoutContext);
        }

        @Override
        public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
            return new CustomLinkRenderer((Link) getModelElement());
        }
    }

    private static class CustomParagraphRenderer extends ParagraphRenderer {
        public CustomParagraphRenderer(Paragraph modelElement) {
            super(modelElement);
        }

        @Override
        public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
            return new CustomParagraphRenderer((Paragraph) modelElement);
        }

        @Override
        public LayoutResult layout(LayoutContext layoutContext) {
            LayoutResult result = super.layout(layoutContext);
            TargetCounterHandler.addPageByID(this);
            return result;
        }
    }

    // For now we have to create a custom renderer for the root document to propagate the
    // target counter handler to the renderer that will be used on the second layout process
    // This is going to be improved in future iText versions
    private static class CustomDocumentRenderer extends DocumentRenderer {
        public CustomDocumentRenderer(Document document, boolean immediateFlush) {
            super(document, immediateFlush);
        }

        @Override
        public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
            CustomDocumentRenderer renderer = new CustomDocumentRenderer(document, immediateFlush);
            renderer.targetCounterHandler = new TargetCounterHandler(targetCounterHandler);
            return renderer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Aexey, is this still the way to do it in iText7 v8.0.3? You mentioned several times that "this is going to be improved in future iText versions" (need to subclass the DocumentRenderer; we have to prepare the handler for relayout manually).